Let $\pi\colon C\left(X\right) \to M_{n}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ be a $C^*$-algebra homomorphism. How to describe its form?
Let $\pi\colon C\left(X\right)\to M_{n}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ be a $C^*$-algebra homomorphism, where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $M_n\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ is the matrix algebra. How to describe its form?
As we all know, when $n=1$, we can find some $x\in X$ such that $\pi\left(f\right)=f\left(x\right)$ for all $f\in C\left(X\right)$. If $n>1$  can find $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in X$ such that $$
\pi\left(f\right) = \operatorname{diag}\left(f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n)\right), 
$$
for all $f\in C\left(X\right)$?

I have edited your last sentence so that it asks the question I hope was the one you intended

This is true, up to unitary conjugation. This is because $\pi(C(X))$ is a commutative $C^\ast$-subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, hence it is contained in some maximal commutative $C^\ast$-subalgebra $A \subset M_n(\mathbb{C})$. It is a standard fact (which can be proved by the spectral theorem) that such an algebra $A$ is the diagonal algebra conjugated by some unitary $U$. To put it another way, there exist linear functionals $\varphi_1, \cdots, \varphi_n \in C(X)^\ast$ s.t.,
$$\pi(f) = U \, \text{diag}(\varphi_1(f), \cdots, \varphi_n(f)) \, U^\ast$$
From the fact that $\pi$ is a $\ast$-homomorphism, it is easy to deduce that all $\varphi_i$ are characters. Any character on $C(X)$ is of the form evaluation at a point in $X$, so there exist $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in X$ s.t.,
$$\pi(f) = U \, \text{diag}(f(x_1), \cdots, f(x_n)) \, U^\ast$$

Thank you very much for your answer. Can you give me more specific method to show the maximal commutative C*-algebra $A\subset M_{n}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ is the diagonal algebra conjugated by some unitary $U$?

@HaoWang Since $A$ is a finite-dimensional commutative $C^\ast$-algebra, by Gelfand duality it is of the form $\mathbb{C}^m$ for some $m$. Thus, it is generated by a single normal element $x \in A$. By spectral theorem, $x$ admits an orthonormal eigenbasis ${e_i}_{i=1}^n$. Thus, the diagonal algebra w.r.t. ${e_i}$ (which is just the usual diagonal algebra conjugated by a unitary $U$ which changes basis to ${e_i}$) commutes with $x$ and therefore also with $A$. Since $A$ is maximal commutative, the diagonal algebra conjugated by $U$ must be contained in $A$…

@HaoWang … Then by a direct computation, one can check that the diagonal algebra is maximally commutative, whence so is the diagonal algebra conjugated by $U$. Thus, $A$ must be the diagonal algebra conjugated by $U$.

@DavidGao if you invoke Gelfand duality, then $A = \bigoplus_{i=1}^m \mathbb Ce_i$ where the $e_i$ must be orthogonal self-adjoint idempotents, hence it is immediate that $A$ is diagonalisable.

@DavidGao Thank you very much your explanation. The most crucial idea is that every finite dimensional commutative  $C^*$-algebra must be the form of  $\oplus_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{C}e_{i}$, where $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ are mutually orthogonal projections. Thank you again.

@HaoWang Consider accepting the answer if you find it satisfactory.

Writing things a little more invariantly, the question asks for a classification of $*$-homomorphisms from $C(X)$ the $\mathbb C$-valued functions on $X$ a compact Hausdorff space, to $\mathcal E=\mathrm{End}(V)$ where $(V,\langle -,-\rangle)$ is a Hermitian inner product space, so that $\mathcal E$ is equipped with a $*$-operation given by
$$
\langle \alpha(v),w\rangle = \langle v,\alpha^*(w)\rangle, \quad \forall v,w \in V
$$
Theorem: If $\pi \colon C(X) \to \mathrm{End}(V)$ is a $*$-homomorphism then $V=\bigoplus_{i=1}^m E_i$ an orthogonal direct sum and for each $i\in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ there is a point $y_i \in X$ such that
$$
E_i = \{v \in V: \pi(f)(v) =f(y_i).v, \forall f \in C(X)\}.
$$
The classification follows from the following basic fact -- see e.g. chapter 7A of Axler's book.
Fact: any normal operator on a complex inner product space is orthogonally diagonalisable.
Proof of the Theorem: Let $A=\pi(C(X))$ be the image of $\pi$. Then $A$ is a commutative $*$-stable subalgebra of $\mathrm{End}(V)$. In particular if $a\in A$ then $a^*\in A$ and hence as $A$ is commutative $aa^*=a^*a$, so that the elements of $A$ are all normal operators, and are thus all orthogonally diagonalisable by Fact 1 above.
Now if $A= \pi(C(X))$ then $A$ is a commutative subalgebra of $\mathcal E$, and since $C(X)$ is a $*$-algebra via pointwise conjugation and $\pi$ satisfies $\pi(\bar{f})= \pi(f)^*$ it follows that $A$ consists of normal operators. By Fact 1, it follows that every $a \in A$ is orthogonally diagonalisable.
Lemma: If $a_1,\ldots, a_k$ are commuting normal operators, then there is a vector $v \in V$ which is a simultaneous eigenvector for the $a_i$, $1\leq i \leq k$.
Proof: Use induction on $k$, the case $k=1$ being trivial. If $k>1$ then let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r$ be the eigenvalues of $a_k$ so that $V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^r U_i$ is an orthogonal direct sum, where $U_i = \{v\in V: a_k(v)= \lambda_i.v\}$ is the $\lambda_i$-eigenspace of $a_k$. Then since $a_ia_k=a_ka_i$ for each $i$, $1\leq i\leq k-1$, the $a_i$ preserve both $U_i$ and $U_i^{\perp} = \bigoplus_{j \neq i} U_j$, so that both $a_i$ and $a_i^*$ preserve $U_1$ and hence the $a_i$, $1\leq i\leq k-1$, restrict to normal operators on $U_1$, and so by induction, there is a vector $u\in U_1$ such that $u$ is a simultaneous eigenvector for $a_1,\ldots,a_{k-1}$. Since $u$ is also clearly an eigenvector for $a_k$, we are done.  $\phantom{abab}\square$
Now pick a basis of $A$, say $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$. Applying the Lemma to the set $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$ we see that there is a $v \in V$ with $a_iv=\lambda_i.v$ for some scalars $\lambda_i$. Let $\mu \colon A \to \mathbb C$ be given by $\lambda(a)= \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i c_i$ where $a= \sum_{i=1}^k c_ia_i$. Then if we set
$$
E_{\lambda} :=\{v \in V: a(v)=\lambda(a).v\} 
$$
we have $u \in E_{\lambda}$ so that $E_{\lambda}\neq \{0\}$. Moreover, since $\pi$ is a $*$-homomorphism, it follows that $\lambda\circ \pi\colon C(X)\to \mathbb C$ is also a $*$-homomorphism, so that $\lambda\circ \pi(f)= f(y_1)$ for some $y_1 \in X$, and $E_{\lambda} = \{v \in V: \pi(f)(v)=f(y_1).v\}$. (Here we are assuming the case $\dim(V)=1$, i.e. that the maximal ideals of $C(X)$ are given by the points of $X$).
But now since $A(E_{\lambda})\subseteq E_{\lambda}$, $A^*(E_{\lambda}^{\perp}) \subseteq E_{\lambda}^{\perp}$, hence since $A^*=A$ (as $\pi$ is a $*$-homomorphism) it follows that $V = E_{\lambda}\oplus E_{\lambda}^{\perp}$ where the action of $A$ respects the orthogonal direct sum. But then since $\dim(E_{\lambda}^{\perp})<\dim(V)$ the theorem follows by induction on $\dim(V)$.
